# Clustering search phrases

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification

Am working on this problem where I need to cluster search phrase based on what they are looking for (for now, let's assume they are looking for only places, such as bookstore, supermarket, ..)

**"Where can I find a cheesecake ?"**
could get clustered probabilistically to 'desserts', 'restaurants', ...

**"Where can I buy groceries ?"**
could get clustered probabilistically to 'supermarkets', 'vegetables', ...

Assume for beginning with, a set of what the search phrases could get classified to, already exists.

I looked into topic modeling but I feel like I might be heading the wrong direction. Any suggestions on how to get started off / what to look into would be highly helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems like `query rewriting`. http://www.slideshare.net/lundjohnson/2011-07-27-bay-area-search

Comment: What kind of data do you have available?

Answer (score 0):

Topic modelling certainly provides one possible solution. Induce a topic model from a large corpus, as representative as possible of the texts you're indexing and searching with. Then represent each query as the posterior over the topics given the query. If you want to obtain a clustering of queries, you could then do so on this reduced set, or if you're doing IR you could use the resulting vectors instead of the original bag of words.

If this isn't what you want, can you elaborate on the problem? What do you hope to do with the clustered queries?